# Equivalent norms and orthogonality

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Is orthogonality transferred by equivalent norms in any $L^p$ space? it looks so since orthogonality  is defined in terms of norms.

We say that two norm are equivalent is there exists numbers $C$ and $D$ such that for all $x$

$\mid\mid x \mid\mid_{b} C \le \mid\mid x \mid\mid_{a}  \le D \mid\mid x \mid\mid_{b} $

Comment: orthogonality (as I have studied) can be dealt with inner-product. And on $L^{P}$ space, the notion of inner products and norms are related by $\langle x \rangle = \sqrt{ \|  x \| }$ for $x$ $\in$ $X$. where $X$ is a normed linear finite dimensional space. And as $\|  \cdot \|_{1} \sim \| \cdot \| $ for any two norms $\| \cdot \|_{1}$ and $\| \cdot \|$ on a finite dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{K}^{n}$

Comment: How do you define orthogonality without an inner product??

Comment: @ε-δ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement#Banach_spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes in general Banach space because if $\Vert\cdot\Vert_a \sim \Vert \cdot \Vert_b$ are equivalent norms, then
$$(V,\Vert\cdot\Vert_a )^* = (V,\Vert\cdot\Vert_b)^*  $$
so clearly for a subspace $W \leq V$ we have
$$W^{\perp,a} = W^{\perp,b} \leq V^*$$